# using polymer on the client and node.js on the server how to pass variable from node to polymer

Tags: node.js, polymer, ejs

in my app.js:

```
res.render('ingrid_2.ejs', {
    num_visitors: 10
});
```

in my polymer template

```
    properties: {
       visitors:
       {
         type: Object,
         value: 200
       }
    }
```

how to connect the two? can I use an .ejs file variable for this?

Comment: I do not know  .ejs file variable but If I tell through the database,  would it be too simple.? as both server side and client side could access to the same database. there are a lot way due to data type. (special data per user or general data)

Answer (score 0):

In ingrid_2.ejs, you can pass num_visitors as a property to your custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/my-component/my-component.html">
<my-component visitors="<%- num_visitors %>"></my-component>
```

When you load the page and your EJS template is rendered, the output will look like:

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/my-component/my-component.html">
<my-component visitors="10"></my-component>
```

Within your component object, `this.visitors` will then be 10. (Although I recommend changing `type: Object` to `type: Number`.)